# how to add CASCADE to a foreign key that has already been created

Tags: mysql

Employer:

```
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(255)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| corp     | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| type     | char(1)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Employee:

```
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(255)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name         | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| employer_id  | int(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

employer_id references table employer field id.

How do I alter table to add cascading?

Comment: You need to drop and re-create it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we go!

there is no way to simply alter, you have to simply drop and re-create again

```
--To  Drop Foreign key     
ALTER TABLE [table_name] DROP FOREIGN KEY [foreign key];

--To Alter
ALTER TABLE [table_name]
ADD CONSTRAINT [foreign key name from above]
FOREIGN KEY (`[column_name]`) REFERENCES `[other_table]` (`[column_name]`)
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```